# Android: draw borders on LinearLayout

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Now I have a problem about drawing borders on LinearLayout. I draw borders by following codes.

```
   public class Borders{
    int w;
    int h;
    public Borders(int x, int y){
        w = x;
        h = y;
    }

    public void drawBorderInImg(Canvas canvas){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, w, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(w, 0, w, h, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(w, h, 0, h, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, h, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

I create a boolean value and use onclickListener() to control it. By default, the value is false, so there is no border on the screen.

```
   @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            // operate.refresh(ShapeData.figureList1);
            Borders borders = new Borders(img01.getWidth(), img01.getHeight());
            if(img01DrawOrNot){
                borders.drawBorderInImg(canvas);
            }
```

And then I do

```
img01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(img01DrawOrNot){
                    img01DrawOrNot = false;
                } else{
                    img01DrawOrNot = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

I set **android:clickable=true** in xml. It actually works. But, I need to postInvalidate() it. In fact, I can't refresh it because it contains some random shapes, when I do postInvalidate(), all views will change. How can it change automatically? So when I click, it will appear and when I click again, it will disappear. Could someone help me? Cheers!

Comment: Well, this isn't so much an answer to your question but an alternate possibility. You could instead use a Nine patch with only borders on it (no fill). http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 7):

if you like, try this.

(create this layout in your drawable folder)
**layout_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp" />

            <corners android:radius="1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="200dp" android:background="@drawable/layout_border" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thx, but how can I control it? I want to click it and toggle it